# RLS in Power BI Embedded (App Owns data) with Azure analysis service live connection

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I am using Power BI Embedded (App owns data) version with Azure analysis service live connection. I want to implement RLS. when userlogged into website then I need to read the data security context(Eg: cutomer_id, service_id, etc.,), For this, I want to pass these values (Eg: cutomer_id, service_id, etc.,) to the azure analysis server instance and then use Role filtering in the anlalysis server instance to restrict the data. Can I read the passed values in the analysis server role filters. Can I use customdata() function to achieve this. If it is possible, can you please help me in achieving this.

Comment: Did you ever figure out whether this was possible @Srinu?