# How to configure UPN mapping/CustomData for Azure Analysis Services and PowerBI Embedded

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded, azure-analysis-services, data-gateway

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468992/rls-in-power-bi-embedded-app-owns-data-with-azure-analysis-service-live-connec).

I have a .Net Core Web App that embeds a PowerBI report, this report needs has Row Level Security applied at the data level in **Azure Analysis Services** using an on-premises data gateway.

I have configured the [`EffectiveIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security#applying-user-and-role-to-an-embed-token) to pass through the UPN using the [`CustomData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security#using-the-customdata-feature) option, I have also setup a role and DAX query on the role to filter the rows.

I have also setup the SQL Server Profiler as per [this post](https://www.kasperonbi.com/using-customdata-and-ssas-with-power-bi-embedded/) and can confirm that the values being set inside `CustomData` are being passed through to Analysis services.

In the non-Azure version of Analysis Services, you can configure the data gateway inside the PowerBI web portal to [map usernames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-enterprise-manage-ssas#map-user-names. Since someone else setup the gateway (in Azure), and Azure Analysis Services is not a supported Data Source Type ([not an option in the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuEMp.jpg)). I need to know if it is possible to view/change the [Effective User names/CustomData setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/media/service-gateway-enterprise-manage-ssas/gateway-enterprise-map-user-names_02.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out, as far as I can tell UPN mapping is enabled by default.

In my specific case I ended up using the `CustomData` option as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-row-level-security#using-the-customdata-feature). Initially this wasn't behaving as expected because on my Azure Analysis Services Database I had two row filters, one on the main data table that was comparing the user's email against the [`USERPRINCIPAL()`](https://dax.guide/userprincipalname/) DAX function, then the filter that I added against the user table comparing the user's email against [`CUSTOMDATA()`](https://dax.guide/customdata/) DAX function.

To get this to work I ended up removing my own filter against the user table and replacing the use of the `USERPRINCIPAL()` function in the initial filter with `CUSTOMDATA()` - I verified this change with our BI guy and he was happy with it.

I hope this saves someone else the trouble I had.